# StableDiffusion - PyTorch - has_float64_support(): incompatible function arguments

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to install StableDiffusion web UI to my not so powerful pc which has an AMD graphic card (Display: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Render: AMD Radeon HD 7600M series).
I followed instructions on [this link](https://github.com/AUTOMATIC1111/stable-diffusion-webui/wiki/Install-and-Run-on-AMD-GPUs) to install. But after installation when I started the web.settings.bat it gives me error below:

```
File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\launch.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\launch.py", line 35, in main
    start()
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\modules\launch_utils.py", line 443, in start
    import webui
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\webui.py", line 54, in <module>
    from modules.call_queue import wrap_gradio_gpu_call, wrap_queued_call, queue_lock  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\modules\call_queue.py", line 6, in <module>
    from modules import shared, progress, errors
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\modules\shared.py", line 756, in <module>
    directml_do_hijack()
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\modules\dml\__init__.py", line 64, in directml_do_hijack
    if not torch.dml.has_float64_support(device):
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\modules\dml\backend.py", line 41, in has_float64_support
    return torch_directml.has_float64_support(get_device(device).index)
  File "C:\StableDiffusion\stable-diffusion-webui-directml\venv\lib\site-packages\torch_directml\device.py", line 44, in has_float64_support
    return torch_directml_native.has_float64_support(device_id)
TypeError: has_float64_support(): incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: int) -> bool
```